# iOS - Dual Status bar overlay

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios10.3

[image]

[image]

I have been working on an application, and distributed it for testing one of my colleague has got this issue, the screenshot shows that has dual status bar, i asked him to reproduce the issue or give me the steps so that i can resolve it or at least find why or how it is happening, but unfortunately he was not able to reproduce the issue.

FYI i am using default status bar and i have done only one change with respect to the status bar style other than this there is no modification done to the status bar

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]
```

Have anyone of you faced this issue? if so can you provide me some feedbacks or help

Thanks

Comment: Show any code related to modification of status bar.

Comment: that is bug of iPhone... I have this in WhatsApp also... I would say Ignore it...

Comment: @nayem here is the piece of code 
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

Comment: @FahimParkar, thanks for your reply. Do you have a scenario to reproduce it. Like you said you faced it in whatsapp too, so do any particular idea? And yes i will wait for apple to update the bug if they are aware of it.
Thanks

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan no way to reproduce... but this happen especially when try to take photo then minimize app n open again... but not always...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I tried to pull the Notification centre, and for a while i held it parallel to status bar and then released it, for a while i was able to see the dual status bar. It tried it in iphone 6S(12.1). With respect to image i can't say this is might be the exact scenario, since the font color are different time stamp is missing or might be update. Not sure it a bug or functionality by apple.